# Add social media sharing buttons to chat event pages

Tags: feature-request, chat

It would be convenient if the chat event page (e.g. [the recommendation chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/science-fiction-fantasy?tab=schedule)) had the same social media sharing buttons as questions do (i.e. Twitter and Facebook).  This would make it easier to promote upcoming events.  The link in the tweet (and whatever Facebook calls a post? status update? thing) would take you to the event page, where you could register interest.